# Grasshopper on International Sim Cards

Tags: usa, international-travel, cellphones

Will IP Phone Software Services such as Grasshopper or the like, function with an international Sim Card and no phone number (except the international Number)?

We jump from country to country regularly and require 24/7 cell + sms access on a local (to the USA) phone number. We struggled to find a carrier that supported the countries we're traveling to. So, we've been using local sim cards (local to the country we're in) with no phone access on the card while attempting to utilize a soft phone / ip phone software service unsuccessfully.

I've been struggling to find a solution to this. We tried grasshopper and ported our 3 USA phone numbers to it. However, once the ports completed, nothing seems to work except outgoing calls. I'm not sure anyone at Grasshopper understands fully what we're trying to accomplish (to have working USA numbers, fully accessible while we travel to any random country).

I'd switch / port our numbers to another similar carrier if needed. I'm not sure if I'm just wasting my time and this kind of setup will never work? Do these sort of services require a sim card present with a local carrier to process the SMS / Phone calls thru somehow? Or, am I just having bad luck with Grasshopper and this should work?

Comment: Have you considered Google Fi?

Comment: I also use Google Fi. It has been seamless everywhere I have traveled. But keep in mind that part of the problem may be your device. Most phones sold in the USA do not have the necessary radio frequencies to operate on 4G LTE outside of North America.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If the phone didn't support any local frequency band, the problem would not just be limited to incoming calls. It would not be possible to call out either.

Comment: @David Google Fi Has the same limitation. "Excessive roaming" will cause a disconnect. Yes, the radios are all tri-mode / will work anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That simply isn't the case anymore, most newer US sold phones will work anywhere - including the ones we've been using.

Comment: @maplemale That's been true of iPhones for a few generations now, I'm glad to hear it's apparently also true of Android devices now.

Comment: I think I'm finding out the answer to this is a most definite NO. As I'm now at the 3rd level of senior support with Grasshopper after 5 days, and it seems they are indicating a US Sim Card with SMS and Phone service is an all-out requirement.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ya, I've got a Samsung S5 that has Global, LTE, CDMA, GSM and UMTS. I think the Global and GSM started appearing around the S5 even for phones locked to carriers like Verizon.